# Core Data - Changing attributes type

Tags: swift, core-data, swift3

I have a project and I am using core data.

I have some entities, with attributes. When I started the project I choose some atributes and now I want to change their types (Int to String for example).  ANd so I did it.

THe thing is, I am getting errors...

I checked the code, I think every thing is ok.
I even deleted the entire entity and made a new one with some name but it doesn't work.

How can I change it with success?

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: You're probably getting a database mismatch.  Delete your app from the test device and re compile/install.  In the future, especially after it is deployed, you need to look into Migrating the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use code data migration for this by creating new version..

Answer (score 1):

To change data types you need to create a new version of the database, you can not just simply modifie it because that way your users would have to delete and redownload your app every time you change something.
[Here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/27657/how-to-perform-a-lightweight-core-data-migration) you can read how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The simulator or device you are running the app on still 'remembers' the old type and data. Simply hold down on the app and press the 'X' to delete it. When you press play in XCode it will reinstall the app with the new data types.